# Error in R when running an sqldf function: ‘package ‘RSQLite.extfuns’ could not be loaded’

Tags: r, sqldf

I'm getting an error when I'm running the sqldf command in R: ‘package ‘RSQLite.extfuns’ could not be loaded’

Here's my code:

```
install.packages("RSQLite")
library("RSQLite")
install.packages("sqldf")
library("sqldf")
Ent_forecast<-sqldf("select day,
                year,
                date,
                sales_offered_calls
                from R_input")
```

The first error (after the install): 
Error: package ‘RSQLite.extfuns’ could not be loaded

The second error (after using function: sqldf): 
Error: could not find function "sqldf"

...I think this may have something to do with the RSQLite.extfuns package being removed from the CRAN library:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite.extfuns/index.html

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: can you do a `sessionInfo()` to show which version of `RSQLite` and `sqldf` you have loaded?

Comment: R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RSQLite_1.0.0 DBI_0.3.1     gsubfn_0.6-6  proto_0.3-10 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tcltk_3.0.2 tools_3.0.2

Comment: Update R, update your packages and all will be fine.

Comment: Yes. Version 3.0.2 is somewhat older now. We're at version 3.1.2. The latest version of sqldf required R (≥ 3.1.0)